# Peticiones POST con Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, post, get, postman, http-post

Les comento mi problema, hace un tiempo empecé un proyecto usando la api de whatsapp en principio iba a ser solo un bot, pero decidí ampliarlo y hacerle un frontend que además de que haya un bot una persona pueda dar soporte.

Estoy queriendo desde hace unos días hacer una petición de tipo POST al servidor (fly.io) en el cual esta alojado el código, el problema es que al hacer una solicitud GET me devuelve los resultados sin problema, pero con POST no sucede lo mismo.

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
    async function sendTextFront(textResponse, number){ 
    
        const data = JSON.stringify({
            "messaging_product": "whatsapp",    
            "recipient_type": "individual",
            "to": number,
            "type": "text",
            "text": {
                "preview_url": true,
                "body": textResponse
            }
        })
        whatsappService.SendMessageWhatsApp(data);
        await makeRequest(data);
        return Promise.resolve(data);
    };
    
    async function makeRequest(data) {
        let config = {
            method: 'post',
            maxBodyLength: Infinity,
            url: 'https://***.fly.dev/whatsapp/api/sendmessage',
            headers: { 
              'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
            },
            data : data
          };
        try {
            const response = await axios.request(config);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
```

Así es como tengo configurado para realizar la petición POST para que me aparezca a mi, luego en las rutas tengo establecido lo siguiente:

```
    .post(`/api/sendmessage`, (req, res) => {
        const datos = whatsappController.send(req, res)
        if (datos) {
            res.status(200).json({
                success: true,
                data: datos,
            });
        } else {
            res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                error: "Error al enviar el mensaje",
            });
            console.log(datos);
        }
    })
```

Debo aclarar que el archivo index lo tengo configurado de la siguiente manera:

```
    const yourapp = process.env.FLY_APP_NAME;
    
    const app = express();
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
    
    const HOST = "0.0.0.0";
    
    app.use(express.json());
    
    app.use("/whatsapp", apiRoute);
    
    app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => (console.log(`Server listen in port: ${PORT} and Host in: ${HOST}`)));
    console.log(`Back end in: https://${yourapp}.fly.dev/whatsapp/messages`);
```

Al enviar por postman una solicitud post a la url (https://----.fly.dev/whatsapp/api/sendmessage) el mensaje llega sin problema al whatsapp debido a que uso una función que tengo establecida
`whatsappService.SendMessageWhatsApp(data);` y envía los mensajes usando la api de whatsapp.

Pero esta misma si ingreso a la url que me debe mostrar la data
https://----.fly.dev/whatsapp/messages no me muestra nada, y me aparece **Cannot GET /whatsapp/api/sendmessage**

Lo que me da a entender que esta esperando un metodo get, lo cual como verán en las rutas no lo tengo declarado así.

Adjunto una imagen de que es lo que me muestra postman (la url para este caso esta modificada por fines de seguridad):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y también les muestro que es lo que me aparece en el navegador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo fly.io al recibir la petición de postman me muestra estos errores

```
 gru [info] node:internal/errors:491

 gru [info] ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);

 gru [info] ^

 gru [info] Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

 gru [info] at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5)

 gru [info] at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:663:11)

 gru [info] at ServerResponse.header (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)

 gru [info] at ServerResponse.send (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12)

 gru [info] at ServerResponse.json (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:278:15)

 gru [info] at Object.send (/app/src/controllers/whatsappControllers.js:81:25)

 gru [info] at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {

 gru [info] code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'

 gru [info] }

 gru [info] Node.js v18.13.0

 gru [info] INFO Main child exited normally with code: 1

 gru [info] INFO Starting clean up.

 gru [info] WARN hallpass exited, pid: 238, status: signal: 15 (SIGTERM)
```

Entiendo que puede ser un error de los headers, si alguien tiene una respuesta acerca de como hacer para recibir la solicitud post con la respuesta a través del navegador y que me traiga la data se lo agradezco, también no se si con el metodo post debo especificarle alguna configuración al servidor mas de la que establecí en el código.